# AngularJS: Function calls between two Directives not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created two directives, List and Entry. List gets an array as an attribute and displays one Entry for each arraymember.

List directive:

```
app.directive('list', function() {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'E';

    directive.scope = {};
    directive.scope.listArray= '=';

    directive.template = '<ul id="list">' +
                             '<track-element ng-repeat="entry in listArray" entry="entry" onSelect="onSelectEntry()"></track-element>' +
                         '</ul>';

    directive.link = function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        scope.onSelectEntry = function() {
            alert("hi");
        };
    };
    return directive;
});
```

Entry directive:

```
app.directive('entry', function() {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'E';

    directive.scope = {};
    directive.scope.entry= '=';
    directive.scope.onSelect = '&';

    directive.template = '<li class="entry" data-index="{{entry.ID}}" ng-click="onSelect()">' +
                             '<p>{{entry.content}}</p>' +
                         '</li>';

    return directive;
});
```

I pass a function `onSelectEntry` from the list directive to the entry directive. If clicked, this function should be executed.

But this function never gets executet. Any ideas?

Comment: try taking the brackets off `onSelectEntry()` in your list directive template, you are passing the result the function, not a reference to it

Comment: fix attribute camel case

Comment: thanks charlietfl. Changed the attribute to on-select and now it works.